# How to restrict mouse events to current element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this, addeventlistener

I'm trying to change the background image of a div when a user hovers over and clicks it.  I'm stuck on limiting the images from changing to ONLY the element on which the user is hovering/clicking.  In this example, all of the buttons will change when one div is hovered on/clicked.  This is something I'm trying to replicate that's already working in jQuery.  I'm guessing it's possible to use "this" but all of the ways I've tried so far result in errors.

Bonus points for anyone who cal tell me why the alert happens on page load in Firefox but not IE or Chrome

**JavaScript**

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); 
var i;

function iconDown(e) {
    for (i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].style.backgroundPosition = '0px -61px';
    }
}

function iconUp(e) {
    for (i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].style.backgroundPosition = '0px -122px';
    }
}

function iconOver(e) {
    for (i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].style.backgroundPosition = '0px -122px';
    }
}

function iconOut(e) {
    for (i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].style.backgroundPosition = '0px 0px';
    }   
}

function processAction() {
        alert("Working!");

}

function Init () {
    for (i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {

            if (document.addEventListener) {  // all browsers except IE before version 9

                buttons[i].addEventListener ("mousedown", iconDown, false);
                buttons[i].addEventListener ("mouseup", iconUp, false);
                buttons[i].addEventListener ("mouseover", iconOver, false);
                buttons[i].addEventListener ("mouseout", iconOut, false);
                buttons[i].addEventListener("click", processAction, false);

        }
        else {   // IE before version 9
                buttons[i].attachEvent ("onmousedown", iconDown);
                buttons[i].attachEvent ("onmouseup", iconUp);
                buttons[i].attachEvent ("onmouseover", iconOver);
                buttons[i].attachEvent ("onmouseout", iconOut);
                buttons[i].attachEvent("onclick", processAction);
            }
        }
   } 

Init();
```

**CSS**

```
        .btn {width:100px; height:61px; float:left;}
        #BackImg {background: url('images/Back.gif') no-repeat 0px 0px;}
        #NextImg {background: url('images/Next.gif') no-repeat 0px 0px;}
```

**HTML**

```
        <DIV class="btn" ID="BackImg"></DIV>
        <DIV class="btn" ID="NextImg"></DIV>
```

Comment: Correction - the alert is not loading in Firefox anymore.  Bonus points for me!

Comment: Get rid of the for loops in your event handlers? `this` should refer to the button that was clicked, if not `(e || event).target` will.

Comment: in jQuery `if (this==e.target)` it's the thing you clicked on if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any javascript for this. Just use css.

```
.specialClassyClass{
    /*default background position*/
}
.specialClassyClass:hover{
    /*hover state background position*/
}
.specialClassyClass:active{
    /*mouse down background position*/
}
```

For the clicky stuff:

```
var whatever = function(el, ev, handler){
    el.attachEvent?
        el.attachEvent(ev, handler):
    el.addEventListener(ev, handler, false);
}

whatever(button[i], 'click', processAction);
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `event` as the function's name. It's used by many browsers to store the event object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
function processAction(e) {
        var active = document.querySelector('.active'); // get currently active button
        if(active != undefined)      
             active.className = "btn"; // remove active class

        e.target.className = 'btn active' // add active class to clicked element
}
```

then your css can be something like:

```
 .btn {width:100px; height:61px; float:left;background: orange;}
  .active {background: red;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NXVv7/